# IIS Configuration via PowerShell: Disable Default Document

Tags: iis, powershell, default-document

I’m able to query the default document list in IIS using the following PowerShell code:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "//defaultDocument/files/add" -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Name "value" | select value
```

…but I want to disable the default document feature altogether to address a vulnerability. I’ve not found much on disabling the feature via PowerShell but MS documentation says the following can be run to remove a value:

```
remove-webconfigurationproperty /system.webServer/defaultDocument -name files -atElement @{value="foo.html"}
```

Is this really the only way to disable the feature? I’ve not found anything that suggests it can simply be disabled like you can in the IIS administration console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove features from IIS, you should the Dism cmdlets, in your case:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument
```

If you want to disable it inside of IIS for the whole server, you can use:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/defaultDocument" -name "enabled" -value "False"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works a treat! Is this process documented anywhere? I've been searching the web for some time now and not found the above or anything near to this!

Comment: I don't think every possible configuration change in IIS is documented, I just know it pretty well, so I can figure out how to do things based on previous experience.

Comment: Ok thanks. I like to get a good understanding of how to do the things I want but as mentioned, didn't find a lot for this cmdlet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable only for 1 site, use the following code:

```perl
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter "system.webserver/defaultdocument" -pspath "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -name "enabled" -Value "False"
```

Replace `Default Web Site` with the name of the site you want to disable

Credit to Peter for the original answer